# My printer Samsung SCX-4720FN printing unlimited pages of source code

Tags: printing, printer

I have a Samsung SCX-4720FN.

My problem is when I'm going to print anything from my PC to my printer, the printer is printing source code instead of my words or my printing command.

My printing result appear like this:

[image]

But what I actually wanted to print is:

[image]

- I tested this on many different PCs, so I don't think the problem from my PC.
- When I scan a document from the same printer the result is good and no problems. The problem is just when I make command from the PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the OS. By "PC", I assume you are using Windows. There is a [thread for Mac issues](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2010855), though.

First, be sure you have installed the [correct drivers](http://www.fixya.com/support/t5255497-scx_4720fn_prints_gibberish). Download the correct driver from Samsung*. The driver is shown as compatible with versions through Windows 8; it is possible Windows 10 will not work with it. In that case, you might test the printer in another OS, e.g. Linux. You can run a "Live" version such as [Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-usb-stick-on-linux) from a USB flash drive without installing on the HDD. If that works, you can print from the USB drive or install Linux.

If that does not resolve the issue, then try resetting the device to its defaults.

- Enter [Tech Mode](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1391440/Samsung-Scx-4720f.html?page=89#manual) by pressing <kbd>Menu</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>
- [Clear all memory](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1391440/Samsung-Scx-4720f.html?page=90#manual) by selecting `MEMORY CLEAR`.
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- Select your country group.

* The link to a site that *claimed* to have Samsung drivers has been removed at the suggestion of @hdhondt. The URL is below, rather than as a link, but I cannot vouch for the safety of the files.

*Possible driver site*: https://www.driversamsung.com/samsung-scx-4720fn-download-driver/

Comment: I doubt the driversamsung site is an official one. If you go to Samsung.com and look for drivers, they send you to HP, where the closest equivalent is the SCX-4727

Comment: @hdhondt, thanks for pointing out the unfounded assumption I'd made. The link has been relocated, with a *caveat* rather than removed, because I could not find a better source for the driver.

Comment: as I pointed out in my answer, the PCL6 driver is part of Win10 (and hopefully also Win7/8)

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is PostScript code. Seeing this implies that you are using a PostScript driver with a printer that is set to expect PCL. The PCL printer will not see any PCL commands and hence assumes it is text. Hence your prints.

To overcome it, make sure the printer expects PostScript. This can usually be done from either the front panel or via the printer's web interface.

With Windows you can usually tell the printer to "auto-switch" language. Windows tells the printer what to expect by wrapping the print job in PJL (Printer Job Language). If you are running a Mac then PostScript is the best setting.

As an aside, note that sending PCL to a PostScript printer will normally produce no output at all. PostScript's default setting is to ignore the rest of the job if any error is detected. With PCL the first character will be an error, so you get nothing. Windows normally sends an error handler as part of a PostScript job, so the printer will print an error message.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the [User's Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/144027/Samsung-Scx-4720fn.html?page=289#manual), I found your printer only supports PCL6. Hence the PostScript driver you are using is the wrong driver for your printer. So the solution is to change the driver for the correct one. Samsung's website does not seem to have any printer drivers. Various other websites offer drivers, some only up to Windows 7; others offer PostScript drivers which obviously won't work.

Windows 10 ships with a driver for your printer so, if you are using Win10, try that one. Go to Devices and Printers, click on Add a Printer, and then on "The Device I want isn't listed". Click on "Add a local printer" and select it from the list. Then select the port you are using. I think Win7 and 8 should also have the drivers as part of the OS.